# How to dynamically load menu items in Layout or MasterPage in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I would like to dynamically load meny items in the _Layout.cshtml file.

How do I do that? Can you point me to a code example doing that? Or something?

I am not looking for any particular fancy way of doing this.

Below I will describe my intention:

I just want a list of different menu items rendering in the left side of the screen. Say there is a hierarchy of menu items in the form of

Categories -> Types -> Brands -> Models.

So intially just a list of the Category menu items render, then one chooses a Category and a list of Type menu items render, one choses a Type and a list of Brand menu items render, one chooses a Brand and a list of Model menu items render, like below:

(The initial appearance of the menu)

Categories:

- Cars
- Boats
- Bikes
- Motorbikes

(Cars is chosen)

Types:

- Coupe
- Truck
- Van
- Convertible

(Coupe is chosen)

Brands:

- BMW
- Volvo
- Ford
- Mercedes

(BMW is chosen)

Model:

- 325i
- 128i
- 650i
- M6
  .

Comment: Does this menu have to dynamically open in an ajaxy way, or is your intention to have a postback every time someone clicks on a menu item, and then have the page re-render?

Comment: I will render a new menu everytime someone clicks a menu item, until they reach the last level in the hierarchy, this site does it in its beginning menu: http://www.patch.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're talking about items specific to the controller or action, you could have the action put something in ViewData that would be read by whatever view renders the menu.

Edit: A working example

The data structure: a self-referential (recursive) table with the following columns:

```
MenuItemId - int, primary key, identity
DisplayName - varchar
ParentMenuItemId - int, nullable, FK to MenuItemId
```

I then inserted the values you identified in your OP, drilling down through Cars / Coupe / BMW.

This is MVC3/Razor, along with an Entity Framework model.

Controller:  (the action takes a nullable int parameter named "id", which means that MVC will automatically route it through the standard routing handler as /Controller/Action/Id)

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

using (Models.StackOverflowTestEntities e = new Models.StackOverflowTestEntities())
{
    // Insert the child menu items based on the current parent
    ViewData["currentMenuItems"] = e.MenuItems.Where(i => (!id.HasValue && !i.ParentMenuItemId.HasValue) || (i.ParentMenuItemId == id)).ToList();

    // Get our breadcrumb trail
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        int? currentItem = id;

        while (currentItem.HasValue)
        {
            var menuItem = e.MenuItems.Where(i => i.MenuItemId == currentItem).First();

            // TODO: make these into actual hyperlinks?
            sb.Insert(0, string.Format(" » {0}", menuItem.DisplayName));

            currentItem = menuItem.ParentMenuItemId;
        }
    }
}

sb.Insert(0, "Root");

ViewData["breadcrumb"] = sb.ToString();
```

View:

```
<div>@ViewData["breadcrumb"]</div>

<ul>
@{
    var menuItems = ViewData["currentMenuItems"] as IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.MenuItem>;

    foreach (var menuItem in menuItems) {
        <li><a href="/Home/Index/@menuItem.MenuItemId">@menuItem.DisplayName</a></li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

This not only shows the appropriate list of items for the specified parent, it also shows the breadcrumb trail back to the root.

Comment: Hi GalacticCowboy, well what is chosen in the first level menu, will govern what menu items are to displayed by the next level. Like the start of this site: http://www.patch.com/ Could you provide a simple code example so that I can get the idea of your suggestion?

Comment: The way that site is doing it is completely different from what you're describing, however (at least in the technical details) - they've only got 2 levels, and then they're going to a completely different subdomain from there.  I can try to put together an example that will match the *behavior*, even if it's not exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you Mr. GalacticCowboy, it was very nice of you to provide me with some code :-)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to elaborate on why they chose to downvote a 6 year old answer?

Answer (score 0):

i would do it in partial view and call it from layout page using RenderPartial. in partial view you can write these as un ordered list like

```
<ul>
   <li>Categories
         <ul class='sub'>
            <li> Cars</li>
            <li> Boats</li>
            <li> Bikes</li>
         </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Types
         <ul class='sub'>
            <li>Coupes</li>
            <li>Trucks</li>
            <li>Van</li>
         </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Brands
         <ul class='sub'>
            <li> BMW</li>
            <li> Volwo</li>

         </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can write some css to display main ul as Menus and open and close inner uls on hover or click. Moreover, you can create a html helper and pass it model containing all these menus and menu items and it will generate menu for you. Morover, you can have a look at [Telerik Menu](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/menu) if you are interested in third party open source solution

Comment: Hi Muhammed Adeel Zahid, I don't think your solution work, because the next menu is dynamically loaded depending on what was chosen in the previous menu. Take a look at my question again.

Comment: The initial menu of this site is like what I would like to do: http://www.patch.com/

Comment: Actually rune, if you take a look at patch.com, the site you were referring to, they do it in exactly this way. You will need to use javascript to hide/show the specific sub-menus.

Comment: yeh they are loading each state and town in first go and hide and show it using javascript

Comment: I looked at this Telerik stuff, but I didn't really comprehend the code. Is it so that any of you guys could provide a simple code example, helping me to do what I would like to do? I must say that I am not having to much programmer skill, I am not so sharp.